# How to convert a python's datetime.tzinfo object to a pendulum's Timezone object?

Tags: python, datetime, pendulum

I know I can convert a `datetime.datetime` to pendulums with

```
from datetime import datetime,timezone
import pendulum

a = datetime(2021,6,1,tzinfo=timezone.utc)
b = pendulum.instance(a)
b.tzinfo.name # the presence of the attribute 'name' means it's a pendulum timezone
type(b.tzinfo) # pendulum.tz.timezone.FixedTimezone
```

but I have a standalone `datetime.tzinfo` , is it possible to convert it to `pendulum.tz.timezone.*`

```
a = timezone.utc # well, imagine that it can be any tzinfo
b = pendulum.xxxxx(a) # that gives tome pendum.tz.timezone class
```

Is there such method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of `pendulum.instance()` you can tell that it relies on a "private" function [`_safe_timezone`](https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum/blob/411d0aa41a5f39c5f4a2f43a3c369c2dd24787db/pendulum/__init__.py#L64-L92) that you can use to convert a `tzinfo` to a pendulum's timezone. Methods/functions that start with an `_` underscore usually indicates that they don't form part of the public API, but the function is there.

In the case of a `tzinfo=timezone.utc` the `pendulum.instance()` will convert the tzinfo object to an offset in hours and pass that to `pendulum.datetime` which will use `pendulum._safe_timezone()` to convert it to a `pendulum.tz.timezone.FixedTimeZone`. But the `_safe_timezone()` also accepts regular `datetime.tzinfo` as input.

```
a = pendulum._safe_timezone(timezone.utc) #  Timezone('UTC')
type(a) # pendulum.tz.timezone.FixedTimezone
```